# Virtual Camera on OBS is Fliped

Tags: v4l2loopback

When I use the Virtual Camera on OBS with v4l2loopback it is flipping the video in the x-axis. Is there a way to reverse it back to normal?

Comment: What have you tried to so far trying to resolve it?

Comment: @telometto Nothing actually, because I don't know a decent way to do it. One way I could do would be by flipping my whole OBS preview, which would be bad as I intend to do live streams on it

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61485726/ffmpeg-flip-horizontally-webcam-to-virtual-video-camera) help solve your issue?